# Rails 4.2 form with two nested attributes in custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I'm trying to create a form to take attendance,
which has a monthly view of all the students in a course,
I've tried a thousand ways to get it working, but I can't.
What am I doing wrong?
year-round attendance is created by creating a student profile,
so when taking the list, it is updated.
The ideal would be to create or update the attendance when taking it,
but it is a problem that I left for after the form worked.

```
# models/class_book.rb
```

```
class ClassBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alumno_profiles

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :alumno_profiles
end
```

```
# models/alumno_profile.rb
```

```
class AlumnoProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :class_book

  has_many :attendances

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendances
end
```

```
# models/attendance.rb
```

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alumno_profile
end
```

```
# class_books_controller.rb
```

```
(...)

def asistencia
  @class_book = ClassBook.find(params[:id])     
end

(...)

def class_book_params
  params.require(:class_book).permit(:nombre, :etc, :etc_2, alumno_profile_attributes:[:id, :class_book_id, atendance_attributes:[:id, :alumno_profile_id, :asistencia, :fecha]])
end
```

```
# routes.rb
```

```
(...)

get 'class_books/:id/asistencia' => 'class_books#asistencia'
```

```
# app/views/class_books/asistencia.html.erb
```

```
(...)

<tbody>
    <%= form_for @class_book do |f| %>

        <% @class_book.alumno_profiles.order(:primer_apellido).each do |alumno| %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= alumno.primer_apellido%> <%= alumno.segundo_apellido%> <%= alumno.nombre%>
                </td>

                <% alumno.attendances.where(fecha: Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).order(:fecha).each do |attendance| %>
                    <%= f.fields_for attendance do |ff| %>
                        <td>
                        <%= ff.check_box :asistencia %> #boolean
                        </td> 
                    <%end%>         
                <%end%>
            </tr>    
        <%end%> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= f.submit "Save" %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%end%>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "create a form to take assistance"?

Comment: @max sorry i translated it wrong. I corrected it!